# if url exists in array do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form which users can enter a "tweet". I ahve some javascript behind the scenes to control what happens when a url is entered.

If a url is entered such as test.com then a new input field will appear.

If a url that is stored in an array is entered, it will and the new input field along with a select option.

here is my javascript:

```
var test = ["test1.com", "test2.com", "test3.com"];
$('#tweet_text_ga').hide();
$('#custom_alias').hide();
$('#tweet_campaign').hide();
$('#tweet_text').keydown(function () {
    var val = this.value;

    if (/\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}/ig.test(val)) {
        $('#custom_alias').show();
    } else {
        $('#custom_alias').hide();
    }

    if ($.inArray(val, test) !== -1) {
        $('#tweet_campaign').show();
    } else {
        $('#tweet_campaign').hide();
    }
});
```

It works fine if just a url is entered. But as soon as you add more text, it disregards if the url is in the array, and removes the select option. I'm not quite sure on how to explain this any better, so i have setup a fiddle to show what i mean.

I hope someone understands and can point me in the right direction

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V98pk/2/)**

Comment: What you want to achieve at the end is an array with all urls written in the textarea?

Comment: Use val.match instead and look over the matching data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are checking if a whole input is in the array: `if ($.inArray(val, test) !== -1)`. You need to retrieve URL from the input using a regex and check that.

Write a regex that retrieves any URL, get that URL and check if it's one of your lucky ones:

```
var urlsInInput = /[a-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}/ig.exec(val);
if (urlsInInput.length == 1 && $.inArray(urlsInInput[0], test) !== -1) {
```

instead of

```
if ($.inArray(val, test) !== -1) {
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V98pk/8/)

Comment: i was looking into using regex, but wasnt sure if you could check against an array of domains?

Comment: `regex.test(array[index]);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version handling the first url

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/JWC9v/)

```
$('#tweet_text').keydown(function () {
    var val = this.value;
    var urls = val.match(/[a-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}/ig);
    var alias = (urls && urls.length>0) 
    $('#custom_alias').toggle(alias);

    var tweet = urls && urls.length>0 && $.inArray(urls[0], test) !== -1;
    $('#tweet_campaign').toggle(tweet);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What @siledh said. Here is how you could use your current test array

```
var reg = new RexExp(test.join('|').replace(/\./ig, "\\."), 'ig')
if( reg.test(val) ) {
    $('#tweet_campaign').show();
} else {
    $('#tweet_campaign').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the campaign field begins to disappear again is that you compare the whole value of the input with the array. If you just find all domain matches and then compare them to your array it should work.

Like so:

```
var test = ["test1.com", "test2.com", "test3.com"];

$('#tweet_text_ga').hide();
$('#custom_alias').hide();
$('#tweet_campaign').hide();

$('#tweet_text').keyup(function () {

    var alias    = false;
    var campaign = false;

    var domain = /([a-z0-9]+(:?[\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6})/ig;
    var val    = this.value;
    var match  = val.match(domain);

    if (match) {
        alias = true;
        match.forEach(function(e) {
            campaign = campaign || ($.inArray(e, test) !== -1);
        });
    }

    if (alias === true) {
        $('#custom_alias').show();
    } else {
        $('#custom_alias').hide();
    }

    if (campaign === true) {
        $('#tweet_campaign').show();

    } else {
        $('#tweet_campaign').hide();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with your `$.isArray(val, test)`, the value you use is the whole value.
And not sure your purpose, so write a code like this. hope it would help.

http://jsfiddle.net/sheldon_w/KLuK8/

```
var test = ["test1.com", "test2.com", "test3.com"];

var urlReg = /[^\s]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}/ig;
$('#tweet_text_ga').hide();
$('#custom_alias').hide();
$('#tweet_campaign').hide();
$('#tweet_text').keydown(function () {
    var val = this.value;

    var matchedUrls = [];
    val.replace(urlReg, function (matched) {
        matchedUrls.push(matched);
    });

    if (matchedUrls.length > 0) {
        $('#custom_alias').show();
    } else {
        $('#custom_alias').hide();
    }

    $(matchedUrls).each(function (idx, url) {
        if ($.inArray(url, test) !== -1) {
            $('#tweet_campaign').show();
            return false;
        } else {
            $('#tweet_campaign').hide();
        }
    });

});
```